# Extra comma in citing url

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style, url

I'm using the following code to cite an URL,

```
 @manual{real_attacks,
    title={A Brief History of Car Hacking 2010 to the Present},
    note={[Online]. Available: \url{https://smart.gi-de.com/2017/08/brief-history-car-hacking-2010-present/}},
    year={2017}
}
```

but I get an extra comma instead of a dot !
[image]

Also the title is italic which shouldn't be.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn, twoside, journal]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, color, enumerate, amsthm, graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz, subcaption, cite}
    \usepackage{color, xcolor, soul, bm}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
    \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{lemma}[\cite{Mieghem11}]\label{lem: max singular}
            This is my lemma ...
        \end{lemma}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,refs}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: There are several ways to produce bibliographies in LaTeX and the way you are using strongly influences if and how this can be changed. So before we can help you any further we must know which bibliography and citation packages you are loading (`cite`, `natbib`, `biblatex`, ...) and which style you are using (the argument of `\bibliographystyle` for BibTeX-based solutions or the value of the `style` option for `biblatex`). This is best shown in an MWE (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: @moewe Please see the updated question.